# Batch Scripting echo available drives error

Tags: batch-file, scripting

Im having a very weird problem where i want to print out the available usb drives connected on my laptop but when i try to do so this is what comes up on the command line.

[image]

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get deviceid ^| find ":"') do set "List=!List!%%a"


:usb  
echo Avaiable Drive ==^> !List!
set /p "Drive=Enter the letter of the Backup drive : "


echo !List! | find /i "%Drive::=%:" && Echo drive OK || Echo drive do not exist && goto:usb
```

This my code im fairly new to scripting, can someone help me fix the problem or improve the code as i dont know if its the best way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Scripting Backing up files in USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917483/batch-scripting-backing-up-files-in-usb)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - Balor Balor's non sequitur aside, the question you linked is about a folder being incorrectly created while this question is about text being incorrectly displayed. They're totally different questions.

Comment: @somethingdark. Yes and no. If the OP had a look at the answer presented in the other question he would have not had this question. You can compare Stephan's answer to mine and see my point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the ugly `wmic` line ending, which includes an additional `CR` (Carriage Return). There are many ways to eliminate it, but in your situation simply use `delims=:` does the trick (and additionally removes the colon, which is a good idea for the following).

Let me suggest another way for User input (using `choice`, which eliminates the need to re-check the drive):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "list= "
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get deviceid ^| find ":"') do set "List=!List!%%a"

choice /m "Enter the letter of the Backup drive : " /c %list%
set drive=!list:~%errorlevel%,1!:
echo Drive is %drive%
```